# CPLEX - constraints matching supply-demand

Tags: constraints, cplex

I have a question regarding the constraint function in CPLEX.

I have a situation where a number of camps needs to be supplied with stocks from 8 ships. The ships need to moor at one of the two harbours. Both transports, namely with the ships (based on ton shipped) and the transport from the harbours to the camps (based on number of ships) are subjective to additional costs.

I need to add a constraint that the amount supplied is at least equal to the demand while the objective is to minimize costs. However, my constraint does not give a correct output.

Can someone help me correct my constraint and explain why it does not work?

```
 /// Indices 
int nrofships = 8;
range ships = 1..nrofships;
int nrofports = 2;
range ports = 1..nrofports;
int nrofmonths = 5; 
range months = 1..nrofmonths;
int nrofcamps = 6;
range camps = 1..nrofcamps;
// Parameters 
float capacity[ships] = [1.250, 2.740, 1.890, 4.980, 2.630, 16.000, 9.610, 3.540];
int demand[camps][months]= [[11, 5, 1, 1, 1],[3, 0, 3, 0, 2],[6, 3, 4, 3, 7],[5, 5, 5, 2, 6],[7, 1, 7, 1, 4],[0, 3, 5, 0, 0]];
int preparation[ships] = [250000, 655000, 412300, 876900, 470025, 3655000, 1914500, 700000];
int transportationcosts[ports][ships] = [[129, 132, 129, 132, 178, 160, 161, 144],[134, 155, 130, 139, 142, 139, 154, 122]];
int distributioncosts[ports][camps] = [[130, 81, 77, 83, 89, 116],[71, 125, 114, 85, 86, 86]];
// decision variable
dvar float+ x[ships][ports][months];
dvar float+ y[ports][camps][months];
dvar boolean binx[ships][ports][months];


//Expression of Decision 
// dexpr float Costs = sum(s in ships, c in camps, p in ports, m in months) preparation[s]*binx[s][p][m];

dexpr float TotalCost = sum(s in ships, m in months, c in camps, p in ports) preparation[s]*binx[s][p][m] + 
         sum(s in ships, m in months, c in camps, p in ports) transportationcosts[p][s]*x[s][p][m] + 
         sum(s in ships, m in months, c in camps, p in ports) distributioncosts[p][c]*y[p][c][m];
 
//Objective function
minimize TotalCost;

//Constraints
constraint ctdemand[ships][camps][months];

subject to {

forall(s in ships, c in camps, m in months) ctdemand[s][c][m]:     
 sum(p in ports) x[s][p][m]*capacity[s] >= demand[c][m];
     
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also, take the [tour]. You shouldn't have posted your followup as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

binx is in the objective but in no constraint.

Don t you need a constraint like

```
forall(s in ships, m in months,p in ports) binx[s][p][m]==(x[s][p][m]>=0.001);
```

?

Plus y is in no constraint either